# Why does 'total' not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, loops, return, iteration

I am trying to print n to the power of p without using Math.Pow().
Here is the pseudocode:

get two integers n , p from the user

using a for-loop calculate the power function n ** p without using Math.Pow() method.
output the result

using a while loop repeat the calculations
output the result

using a do-while loop repeat the calculation
output the result.

I have tried declaring the variables in numerous ways, and return total in the for loop.

```
using System;


public class Powers
{
    
    public static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the base integer here:");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter exponent here:");
        int p = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int total = 1, counter = 1; counter <= p; ++counter)
        {
            
            total = total * n;          
        }

        Console.Write($"{n} to the {p} power is {total}");
    }
}
```

Comment: First - What if the user enters `b`? **Never** trust user input. Instead of `int.Parse`, use `int.TryParse`.  Second - Please read the FAQ: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3094533)

Comment: @ZoharPeled It would crash. **But**: Given this is most probably a "learning effort" with focus on different spots, _I personally_ would mask that out _given that OP is aware of that fact_. I am ok with leaving that part for brevity, as long as they know what they are doing and why. _Maybe_ the teaching authority should provide encapsulation of the "Get User Input safely" functionality for the time being. But I figure they can't be bothered these days. Back in the day, we would have a predefined corset with a "put your code here:" ...

Comment: @Fildor I understand your point and I do agree that learning should be focused, however I also see this as a way for people to learn bad habits. Using `int.Parse` isn't much easier then using `int.TryParse`, so why not start off with better habbits?

Comment: I don't disagree, yes. Same goes for those "but I only save passwords for learning purpose" ... :D

Comment: I'm aware of the importance of validation and value checking, but unfortunately, I have not learned all the ways to do those things yet. My professor is very new and hardly understands many C# mechanics himself. How fun for me.

Comment: _"My professor is very new and hardly understands many C# mechanics himself."_ - Wow, seriously? Then strap in for a rough ride ... haha. But in this case: You may in fact want to explore int.TryParse and how it works and how it affects your code. You might even want to code some alternative versions and bombard them with the silliest wrong input you can come up with. Then see, which one gives you the best experience.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into int.TryParse now

Comment: ^^ You might also want to make use extensively of the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=net-7.0) - being aware that the examples there always focus on the thing they intend to showcase. Everything around that can be utterly sub-par code. => [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Bookmarked the docs, and just successfully implemented TryParse. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables defined in the `for` clause exist only inside of the `for` loop.  If you want it to survive the loop, you have to define it outside:

```
        int total = 1;
        for (int counter = 1; counter <= p; ++counter)
        {
            total = total * n;          
        }

        Console.Write($"{n} to the {p} power is {total}");
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables declared in the `while/for` block are only visible within the loop body and cannot be accessed outside the loop.

You should move the declaration of `total` out of the `while` loop. like this

```cs
 int total = 1;
 for (int counter = 1; counter <= p; ++counter){
    total = total * n;          
 }

 Console.Write($"{n} to the {p} power is {total}");
```

Comment: I updated my answer for better understanding